# How can I use nodejs to ping my local bitcoin node for information?

Tags: zeromq, nodejs

I've set up zeromq so I can listen for blocks & transactions. However I'm not certain how I can ping the bitcoin node for older information.

Is there someway I can ping the bitcoin node for say a block at X height or say a transaction with X id?

Comment: https://github.com/ruimarinho/bitcoin-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getrawtransaction`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/rawtransactions/getrawtransaction/) can be used for transactions if `txindex=1` is saved in config

[`getblock`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/blockchain/getblock/) can be used for blocks

Since you mentioned nodejs, you should check bcoin: https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin

Bitcoin nodes can even be run in [browser](https://bcoin.io/browser/).